# Skip Duplicate entries in row (MySQL)

Tags: sql, mysql, winforms

I have a C# Windows Forms application that extracts rows from a particular column. But, many of the rows have duplicate entries (which is fine), however, I only want to display all unique row values of this one column.

Is there a MySQL query that you know about that can do this?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct (`column`)...
```

or

```
select ... group by `column`
```

Comment: +1 for the GROUP BY alternative. Sometimes DISTINCT doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [DISTINCT](http://www2.nl.freebsd.org/software/vol1/software/mysql/doc/refman/4.1/en/distinct-optimization.html) keyword. It ignores duplicates.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT ColumnName
FROM
    TableName
WHERE
    <condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct(column_name) from your_table
```

Comment: Thanks klausbyskov! :D much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use the DISTINCT keyword in the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column FROM TABLE WHERE ....
```